# passing a structure to a function in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, function, structure

Im working on a project and im trying to pass a structure to a function and I have tried various ways but im still coming up short. Im getting the error message:

> illegal use of this type of expression.

Would really appreciate the help.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

 struct big{
        int day;
        int year;
        char month[10];
        } ;

      void gen(struct big);
      void main()
    {
int choice;

printf("\t\t\t\t\t*MENU*\n\n\n");
printf("\t\tGenerate Buying/Selling Price-------------------PRESS 1\n\n");
printf("\t\tDisplay Foreign Exchange Summary----------------PRESS 2\n\n");
printf("\t\tBuy Foreign Exchange----------------------------PRESS 3\n\n");
printf("\t\tSell Foreign Exchange---------------------------PRESS 4\n\n");
printf("\t\tExit--------------------------------------------PRESS 5\n\n\n\n");
printf("\t\tPlease enter your choice");
scanf("%d", &choice);

if (choice == 1)
{
    gen(big);
}
system("pause");

    }

void gen(big rec)
{
printf("Enter the date in the format: 01-Jan-1993");
scanf("%d %s %d", &rec.day, &rec.month, &rec.year);
}
```

Comment: `void main` is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass the struct definition itself, create an instance of it then pass that.

```
big myBig;
gen(myBig);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Baris. It works. I would love to have a detailed explanation so i can understand why it worked when I created some form of variable ie:myBig from big then using myBig in the function call. I dont really get what you mean by creating an instance.

Comment: The part `struct big{}` is just the definition of the struct. You can't use the name `big` like a variable. `big` is a type like `int`. First you need to create a variable of type `big` then you can use that. An instance is just a variable of some type.

Comment: You'll also need to pass by reference, to allow `gen` to modify `myBig` itself, rather than a local copy.

Answer (score 0):

a> You do not create an object of the structure `big`. You can do that with `big obj;`

b> `void main` is a bad way to program. Use `int main(void)` at least.

c> Pass references instead of a copy on the stack

like this:

```
void gen(big& obj)
{
    printf("Enter the date in the format: 01-Jan-1993");
    scanf("%d %s %d", &rec.day, &rec.month, &rec.year);
}
```

---

You have to create an object of type `big`. `struct big` is just a blue print of a house. While `bigObject` below **is** the house. The actual variable of type `struct big` that HOLDS values etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct big{
    int day;
    int year;
    char month[10];
};

void gen(struct big);
void main()
{
    int choice;
    big bigObject;
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t*MENU*\n\n\n");
    printf("\t\tGenerate Buying/Selling Price-------------------PRESS 1\n\n");
    printf("\t\tDisplay Foreign Exchange Summary----------------PRESS 2\n\n");
    printf("\t\tBuy Foreign Exchange----------------------------PRESS 3\n\n");
    printf("\t\tSell Foreign Exchange---------------------------PRESS 4\n\n");
    printf("\t\tExit--------------------------------------------PRESS 5\n\n\n\n");
    printf("\t\tPlease enter your choice");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

   if (choice == 1)
   {
      gen(bigObject); /*pass bigObject to gen*/
   }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}

void gen(big& rec)
{
  printf("Enter the date in the format: 01-Jan-1993");
  scanf("%d %s %d", &rec.day, &rec.month, &rec.year);
}
```

Comment: thanks. This one is method is new and im trying to understand it

Comment: There is nothing much to it. you created a type with `struct` now you need to define a variable of that type. `big` in your code is a type. `bigObject` is the variable.

Comment: I'm realizing that now. It would be best to pass by reference it seems to allow for better modularity. I suppose using pointers should do the trick

Comment: well I don't like pointers much. I pass reference instead like the way I've done above.